# how to select a specific values from list based on conditions and store in multiple variable

Tags: python, list

I have a list

```
test_list = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f","g","h"]
```

I want to add all the value after `"b"` and `'c'` to another variable but till `"f"` and add all value after `"f"` to another variable , so it will be look like this

```
variable1 = "de"
variable2 = "gh"
```

`"b"` and `"c"` will be always nearby but the index value can be different in another case.

Comment: What did you try?

Comment: As far as I know in python you can simply split array by indexes for example ```variable1=test_list[3:5]```

Comment: You can find the indices for b,c and f and then slice the list according to these indices

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `re.findall`:

```
import re

test_list = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f","g","h"]
s = ''.join(test_list)
var1, var2 = re.findall('bc(.+)f(.+)', s)[0]
```

Output:

```
var1
# de
var2
# gh
```

Comment: Wouldn’t the last line only return the first match, not the second one too?

Comment: @NChauhan You mean because of indexing? `re.findall('bc(.+)f(.+)', s)` will return `[('\\1', '\\2')]` thus unpacking is necessary